# What is the proper way of using S3 as storage for Xodus?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, xodus

When trying to access S3 as storage with Xodus this error is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3:xodusmaster\blobs\version (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.FileSystemBlobVaultOld.<init>(FileSystemBlobVaultOld.java:106)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.FileSystemBlobVaultOld.<init>(FileSystemBlobVaultOld.java:71)
    at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntityStoreImpl.createDefaultFSBlobVault(PersistentEntityStoreImpl.java:422)
    ... 90 more
```

What is the proper way of using S3 as storage for Xodus?

Comment: I don't see xodus mentioning that it supports s3. I think you might wanna try something like s3fs to make s3 more like a file system. But be sure to test extensively. Caching, posix-compliance level and other details could bite.

Comment: @Vin I have tried s3fs but my tests makes Xodus erratic, maybe because S3FS is fuse based. My next plain is to use GlusterFS to test if that would work